# Connecting up to 32 Devices I2C

Tags: i2c, parallel

I'm trying to connect 32 I²C "root of trust" [NXP A71CH](https://www.nxp.com/products/identification-security/authentication/plug-and-trust-the-fast-easy-way-to-deploy-secure-iot-connections:A71CH) devices.

- I'm thinking about a good way that does that, I mean what kind of communication should I use?
- A digital multiplexer that selects a device? but based on what?
- switching on the VDD source? but that needs reinitialization of the device and that takes time.

Comment: Why are you needing 32 of those? They only seem to have 2 addresses so you would need to have at least 16 addressable bus segments.

Comment: @r_ahlskog it's a requirment for a project. which bus do you recommend to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really short: I²C with a bus multiplexer; this is a common problem and it's solved with a bus multiplexer.

However, seriously, the point of having a root of trust is having one root of trust, not 32; hence, your project requirements make me suspect you're either building a test rig for these devices, or you're testing a device that is supposed to work with one of these devices, or you've misunderstood your project requirements.

Comment: I concur with your doubts about the need for 32 such devices in a single system. I don't see any case where it makes sense, but maybe I'm not imaginative enough.

Comment: maybe they are doing a large testbed to figure out how much entropy the internal state of the device has after key generation or something like that. No idea.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would like to parallel the signing of transactions using those 32 devices, I have no solution at my hand right now with FAST speed to connect those 32devices in parallel, signing a transaction costs 7 seconds.. do you have a solution ?

Comment: @Andre that's not what you use a **root** of trust for! You use that root to sign a key that you then use to sign the data. That key can be under control of your CPU.